# Marshalling List<T> with Jersey and JAXB

Tags: java, jersey

I try to output some list of documemts from a resource:

```
@GET
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
public Response getDocuments(@QueryParam("provider") String provider) {
   List<Document> documents = service.getDocuments(provider);
   return Response.ok(
      new GenericEntity<List<Document>>(
        new ArrayList<Document>(documents)) {})
     .build();
}
```

The Document class is not annotated with @XmlElement (I really dislike annotating my nice objects with such low-level stuff...) but I have a registered provider for it:

```
@Service
@Provider
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.TEXT_XML, MediaType.WILDCARD})
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.TEXT_XML, MediaType.WILDCARD})
public class JaxRsDocumentSerializer extends 
     AbstractMessageReaderWriterProvider<Document> {
```

When I call this resource using a client with following code:

```
return getResource().path("/documents")
    .queryParam("provider", provider)
    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).get(new GenericType<List<Document>>() {});
```

I get the dreaded exception:

```
 javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: com.sun.jersey.api.MessageException: 
 A message body writer for Java class java.util.ArrayList, and Java type 
 java.util.List<com.polyspot.model.core.Document>, 
 and MIME media type application/xml was not found
```

I do not understand what's wrong here as I followed code I found elsewhere, including in SO.

Help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you provide any information for class Document? Is in properly annotated?

Comment: Sorry. Yes it is. We have been marshalling/unmarshalling Document instances for "ages" with Jersey.

Comment: Oups. above comment was incorrect, we do not annotate objects but use a custom provider. I updated the question to reflect this.

Comment: maybe its stupbid question, but did you register your provider in web.xml?

Comment: If you talk about the Document provider, the answer is yes. It is automagically picked-up by Jersey upon startup (which BTW is what hogs Jersey startup time)

Comment: I am running into the same problem. But when I call it from postman works right. Only when I am doing it with Jersey Test runs into this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe your `Document` class requires `@XmlRootElement` annonation.

Or, if your Jersey version is >= 1.2, you can try to use `JResposne` instead of `Response`. That allows to avoid usage of `GenericEntity`

Comment: +1 The Document class needs to be annotated with @XmlRootElement.

Comment: Thanks, I added a comment and updated my question, just in case. I would rather stick to pure JAX-RS as I would like to get the choice of implementation for as much time as possible.